# Is it possible to restore database only with .trn files?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

How do I restore database only with .trn (transaction log backup) file?

I did below two steps Microsoft SQL Server Management studio shows "Restoring".

1)

```
RESTORE DATABASE [database_name]
  FROM DISK = N'path\file_name.bak'
  WITH MOVE N'logical_filename' TO N'path\filename.mdf',
       MOVE N'logical_filename_log to N'path\filename.ldf' REPLACE,
       NORECOVERY;
GO
```

2)

```
RESTORE LOG [database_name]
  FROM DISK = N'path\filename.trn'
  WITH NORECOVERY;
GO
```

Comment: remember that `restore ... with RECOVERY` is default .. so if you just use `restore log db_name .. from disk ..` - a `recovery` clause is dafault. So you dont have to specify (but its a good practice to write it, so you know that you are bringing the database online.

Answer (score 3):

Run this:

```
RESTORE LOG [database_name] FROM DISK = N'path\filename.trn' WITH RECOVERY; GO
```

Notice I've changed it to `WITH RECOVERY` - this runs the recovery process and puts the database in a usable state.

Running `WITH NORECOVERY` leaves the database in a state where further log files can be restored.  This state prevents you using the database until you do a `RESTORE LOG ... WITH RECOVERY`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as  per **Tim Chapman** sql blog. But be sure that before restore your database recovery mode was set to 'FULL'. And also set your database recovery mode is set to 'FULL' , for a point in time to recover a data table in future perspective. If you don't have then follow these steps

**Step 1**

From TSQL Commad to change Full recovery Model

> `ALTER DATABASE databaseName SET RECOVERY FULL`

**Step 2**

> To set the full recovery model for your database via the GUI, right
>   click on the database name and select Properties. Then go to option
>   tab and change the recovery model.

A transaction log backup keeps track of all transactions that have occurred since the last transaction log backup; it also allows you to restore your database to a point in time before a database error occurred.

I would like to say that here if you are storing the (.trn) transaction log backup.  You can restore your 
transaction log file with two ways.

**Step1**

As **Mr. Max Vernon** already said

```
RESTORE LOG [database_name] FROM DISK = N'path\filename.trn' WITH RECOVERY; 
GO
```

it recover the database as part of the last RESTORE LOG.

**Step2**

If you Wait to recover the database by using a separate RESTORE DATABASE then do this below statement:

```
RESTORE LOG [database_name] FROM DISK = N'path\filename.trn' WITH NORECOVERY; 
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [database_name] FROM DISK = N'path' WITH RECOVERY;
GO
```

Waiting to recover the database gives you the opportunity to verify that you have restored all of the necessary log backups. This approach is often advisable when you are performing a point-in-time restore.

for ref http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/restore-your-sql-server-database-using-transaction-logs/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx

NB:- As per MSDN BOL, you always explicitly specify either 'WITH NORECOVERY' or 'WITH RECOVERY' in every 'RESTORE' statement to eliminate ambiguity. This is particularly important when writing scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have restored all of the log backups and forgotten to use `WITH RECOVERY` on the last one then run the following.

```
RESTORE LOG [database_name]
WITH RECOVERY;
```